# NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

Tags: nvidia, nvml

I don't know why nvidia-smi doesn't work

what I need to do for fix it?

I think my library and driver version is match but nvidia-smi dosen't recognize it

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru14c.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem and I'm posting here my solution.

In my case NVRM version was `440.100` and driver version was `460.32.03`. My driver was updated by  `sudo apt install caffe-cuda` and I didn't notice that time but I checked it from `/var/log/apt/history.log`.
By following my NVRM version I just used `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440` but it installed 450.102, I don't know why it installed other version and `nvidia-smi` is showing `450.102.04`.

Anyhow after rebooting my PC everything including cuda is working fine now.

I didn't **remove/purge** anything related to nvidia driver. Version `460.32.03` was uninstalled automatically by running `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`

Answer (score 1):

For me, [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/failed-to-initialize-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/190421/3) solution from NVIDIA forums solved the issue.

Run `sudo apt purge nvidia* libnvidia*`

Then `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-520`

Answer (score 0):

Just `reboot` solve the problem in my case